# Known name of the sum of all the point-wise vector products?

Tags: polynomials, vector-spaces

I am encountering a function that I strongly suspect to be known and named in the literature.

Let $\mathbf{A}=(\mathbf{a}_i)_{i\in [1 .. k]}$ be a finite list of $k$ real vectors with $\mathbf{a}_i\in \mathbb{R}^d$. Let $f: (\mathbb{R}^{d})^k \to \mathbb{R}^{d} $ be function defined by:

$$f(\mathbf{A})=\sum_{i,j \in [1 .. k]} \mathbf{a}_i \circ \mathbf{a}_j$$

where $\mathbf{a}_i \circ \mathbf{a}_j$ is the point-wise multiplication between the two vectors (aka Hadamard product), resulting in a vector of the same dimension $d$.

Does the 2nd degree polynomial named $f$ has a name in the literature?

Answer (score 0):

Your term-wise product appears to be a *[Hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices))*.

Comment: Indeed! This is why I used the $\circ$ notation. It's the outer function $f$ that I am trying to identify.

Comment: I don't think it has a name... but I could be wrong.